# Fetching url in python with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm using this code to send Http request inside my app and then show the result:

```
def get(self):
      url = "http://www.google.com/"
      try:
          result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
          self.response.out.write(result)
      except urllib2.URLError, e:
```

I expect to get the html code of google.com page, but I get this sign ">", what the wrong with that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the read() method to read the response. Also good practice to check the HTTP status, and close when your done.

Example:

```
url = "http://www.google.com/"
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    if response.code == 200:
        html = response.read()
        self.response.out.write(html)
    else:
        # handle

    response.close()

except urllib2.URLError, e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the urlfetch service instead of urllib2:

Import urlfetch:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

And this in your request handler:

```
def get(self):
    try:
        url = "http://www.google.com/"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            self.response.out.write(result.content)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Error: " + str(result.status_code))
    except urlfetch.InvalidURLError:
        self.response.out.write("URL is an empty string or obviously invalid")
    except urlfetch.DownloadError:
        self.response.out.write("Server cannot be contacted")
```

See [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Fetching_URLs_in_Python) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what the difference ?

Comment: Not much, in fact when running on App Engine the urllib2 library performs HTTP requests using App Engine's URL fetch service, which runs on Google's scalable HTTP request infrastructure, so behind the scenes they do the same thing, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Fetching_URLs_in_Python